# 3D modelling mine plans - how to set elevations?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to make a 3D model from an old mine plan, I have created a new project in QGIS and added a new geo package layer and checked include Z dimension. Then I have traced a line from the old plan with the add line feature. In vertex editor I have entered the Z values as -10 for all points.

But when I look in the 3D viewer all the lines still seem to be on the zero plane

Am I missing something like Z is not elevation? Or am I going completely wrong with this?

Comment: How did you go about displaying the data in the 3D viewer? Have you made sure your Z values is used for display?

Comment: I just selected 3D Map View from the View Menu? how can i check if the Z values are used for display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your layers properties, select the "3D view" tab, then set `data defined override` for your layer based on the Z value. Then the layer should be displayed correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately the override is only available for polygon layers and not polyline